# NPM start error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

i got this error when i try to run "npm start command". Im on Windows 10. and npm version is 2.13.3. Im trying to run an Express server.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\jmggr_000\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.13.3
3 info using node@v0.12.7
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart Start@0.0.0
6 info start Start@0.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info Start@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: Start@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jmggr_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:214:16)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jmggr_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
10 verbose pkgid Start@0.0.0
11 verbose cwd D:\Intec\mvachirp\chirp\module-3\Finished
12 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
13 error argv "node" "C:\\Users\\jmggr_000\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error node v0.12.7
15 error npm  v2.13.3
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error Start@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the Start@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the Start package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     node ./bin/www
18 error You can get their info via:
18 error     npm owner ls Start
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thank you for the help.

Edit:

It also show the following error:

```
 module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Intec\mvachirp\chirp\module-3\Finished\bin\www:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

I dont know what that means

Comment: That's great. Now how about showing some relevant code?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I attached the code on the post.

Comment: Did you app starts normally when you run `node indexapp.js`?

Comment: @JoseMoreno - no you didn't

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i solved the problem. I wasnt running the DEBUG set: 
set DEBUG=myapp. i did that and solved the problem.

Thank everyone for answer.